# Why does the CAST() function return the wrong date?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to get the date part from a timestamp field. 
I used this SQL query:

```
select timestamp, CAST(timestamp as date) as date from messages
```

I got the following result:

```
--------------------------------------------
|        timestamp        |      date      |
--------------------------------------------
|   2016-05-15 10:22:54   |   2016-05-16   |
--------------------------------------------
```

As shown above, the date field produced returns the wrong date `2016-05-16` whereas the original date is `2016-05-15`.

How can we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use date  not cast because is not casting but a format

```
select timestamp, date(timestamp) as my_date from messages
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks it worked like charm.
But DATE_FORMAT() function also produces wrong format. Why is that?

Comment: Date() extract  the date part of a valid datetime ,,, Date_format change the aspect of the date ... what format do you use .. ?

Comment: I used `%d %M, %Y`

Comment: I repeat the definition  "Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression" so given a valid datetime extract the date part ..no conversion, format or settime setting... involved ..

Answer (score 7):

Thats not a issue !!! Its only set the wrong time_zone. see sample

**get current time_zone**

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone'; -- systemwide setting
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone'; -- session setting
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select t, CAST(t as date) FROM groupme LIMIT 1;
+---------------------+-----------------+
| t                   | CAST(t as date) |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2016-05-15 20:22:54 | 2016-05-15      |
+---------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> SET  time_zone ='-12:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> select t, CAST(t as date) FROM groupme LIMIT 1;
+---------------------+-----------------+
| t                   | CAST(t as date) |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2016-05-14 20:22:54 | 2016-05-14      |
+---------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]>
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to use the DATE_FORMAT function and not the CAST since you are formatting the date like

```
SELECT `timestamp`, DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d) as my_date from messages
```

Also note that both CAST and DATE function internally call Item_date_typecast function so there is no such difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select timestamp, cast(timestamp as date format 'yyyymmddhhmmss') as date from messages
```

Comment: Got SQL Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'format 'yyyymmddhhmmss') as date from messages LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1